# Debian 10 Buster not work Intel UHD 620 graphic

Tags: debian, graphics

Tried to install Debian 10 on Asus Zenbook UX434 but after installation there was a black screen. In console mode I updated the kernel with backports to 5.4 and then were able to log in. But graphics acceleration does not work and everything slows down ...

I installed Ubuntu - everything works fine.

On debian buster:

```
glxinfo |grep -A 15 Extended
Extended renderer info (GLX_MESA_query_renderer):
    Vendor: VMware, Inc. (0xffffffff)
    Device: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits) (0xffffffff)
    Version: 18.3.6
    Accelerated: no
    Video memory: 15895MB
    Unified memory: no
    Preferred profile: core (0x1)
    Max core profile version: 3.3
    Max compat profile version: 3.1
    Max GLES1 profile version: 1.1
    Max GLES[23] profile version: 3.0
OpenGL vendor string: VMware, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0, 256 bits)
OpenGL core profile version string: 3.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 18.3.6
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 3.30

Graphics:  Device-1: Intel driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Display: wayland server: X.Org 1.20.4 driver: vesa unloaded: fbdev,modesetting 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 1080x2160~50Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: llvmpipe (LLVM 7.0 256 bits) v: 3.3 Mesa 18.3.6
```

In Ubuntu acceleration works and there is Mesa Intel(R) UHD Graphics (CML GT2) instead llvmpipe on Debian.

I am new in Unix. Can you help me please how install debian properly in this laptop.

I've already tried installing the firmware (`firmware-misc-nonfree`), it didn't help.

CPU is Intel Core i7-10510U

Comment: What version of Mesa does your Ubuntu set up have?

Comment: Open GL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) UHD graphics (CML GT2) 
OpenGL core profile version string 4.6 (Core profile) Mesa 20.0.8

Comment: Is upgrading to Bullseye an option? It will upgrade Mesa, among other things, which may bring graphics acceleration support.